# SQL query to remove duplicates based on the modified date

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a database table with the following columns regularization_dt, modified_dt and account_id. For a particular whenever an account is updated an entry is added in to the table with new modified_dt for the regularization_dt and account_id.

I want an SQL query to remove duplicates of regularization. Only one entry for the regularization should be selected based on the recent modified_dt.

For example the entries in the table are as follows:

```
regularization_dt | account_id | modified_dt
----------------- | ---------- | ----------
03-28-2013        |  123       |05-26-2014
03-28-2013        |  123       |01-14-2014
05-26-2014        |  123       |05-25-2014
```

The resulting query should yield:

```
regularization_dt | account_id | modified_dt
----------------- | ---------- | ----------
03-28-2013        |  123       |05-26-2014    
05-26-2014        |  123       |05-25-2014
```

How should I remove duplicates of a column based on a different column?

```
select * from history where account_id = 123;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows ?

Comment: Could you reviews your tags. Are your looking for a solution for [tag:oracle] or [tag:mysql] ? Or a cross-vendor solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use an aggregate function and a  `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT   regularization_dt,
         account_id,
         MAX(modified_dt) as modified_dt
FROM     yourtable
GROUP BY regularization_dt,
         account_id;
```

This should return deduplicated rows with only the latest modified_dt for rows with identical regularization_dt and account_id column values.

Comment: What should I do if I have another column domain_item_id which also might be repeated?